# Jquery extend function in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Is there a way to create equivalent of following code in Ember.js

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    functionName: function(myValue){}
});
```

Also I want this function to be global. This function will be used as

```
$('textarea').functionName('value');
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Have you looked at [Helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/writing-helpers/)? They might suit your needs.

Comment: Trying to manipulate the data/content inside the textarea.
Ex: Insert a certain text at specific cursor position.

Comment: You should try to manipulate the data directly, and then bind it to the template, that's usually more aligned with how Ember works.

Comment: Yes. I have edited the comment. That might clear the picture a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extend jQuery and add a function of your own, do it in the initializer. Add the below code in `app/initializers/jquery-extend.js`(Name it as you wish.)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.create({
  name: 'Extend jQuery',
  initialize() {
    jQuery.fn.extend({
       functionName: function(myValue){}
    });
  }
});
```

Now, you can use `$().functionName()` anywhere in your ember app.